# Перенаправление с http на https в Nginx на разных портах

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vds

На VDS несколько приложений на разных портах. Решил сделать самописный SSL-сертификат и сделать перенаправление с http на https для приложения, работающему на **IP_SERVER:8001**

Реализовал перенаправление [по мануалу](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04#step-2-%E2%80%93-configuring-nginx-to-use-ssl) для первого приложения

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name IP_SERVER;

    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5003;
    }

    ...
}

server {
    listen 8001;
    listen [::]:8001;
    server_name IP_SERVER;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Аналогично для второго:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name IP_SERVER;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/USER/APP_DIR/APP.sock;
    }

    ...

}

server {
    listen 81;
    server_name IP_SERVER;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

проверяю:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Выходит сообщение:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "IP_SERVER" on 0.0.0.0:81, ignored
```

Я так полагаю, что это происходит из-за того, что в обоих настройках слушается **443**(пробовал те же порты указать, на которых и работают приложения, но они тогда не работают...).

Как надо правильно прописать? Или такое нельзя реализовать?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:

По HTTP они все нормально работали. Открывались разные сайты на одном IP но на разных портах.

Comment: Если вы собрались сделать два приложения на одинаковом IP_SERVER и одинаковом порту 443 — по какому признаку вы тогда хотите различать, какое конкретно приложение должно открываться? Если вы хотите использовать разные порты — значит указывайте разные порты, а не один и тот же 443

Comment: приложения взаимодействуют с вебом сами по себе или к ним делается proxy_pass из центрального?

Comment: по http они все работали. Вход к ним шел через один IP, но разные порты. Например: http://100.100.100.100:50 и http://100.100.100.100:51. Они в браузере все открывались и работали. Просто решил им HTTPS организовать

Comment: @andreymal, да, я прописывал там вместо 443 порты приложений, но  так они не работают

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov, каждое приложение работает локально на своем порту. Я же говорю, что по HTTP они все прекрасно работали. Я просто решил им всем HTTPS сделать. Но получается, что только 1му могу это сделать..

Comment: @АлексейБелкин порты приложений уже заняты приложениями, значит нужно прописывать какие-то другие незанятые порты

Comment: @andreymal, приложения локально работают на 5000 - 5003 портах. А с глобалки стучатся на 8001, 80, 81, 82.
Или надо для HTTPS другие порты еще указывать?

Comment: сделайте центральный конфиг нжиникса по https, а к приложениям он будет проксировать по старым портам

Comment: @АлексейБелкин на одном порту не могут работать одновременно HTTP и HTTPS. Если упомянутые вами порты уже заняты для HTTP, то для HTTPS необходимо выбрать какие-то другие незанятые порты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) разобрался. Оставлю настройки, если кто в будущем тоже столкнется с этим.

Ниже в настройках:

- IP-Server: 100.100.100.100
- HTTP-port: 81
- HTTPS-port: 91

```
server {
    listen 81;

    server_name 100.100.100.100;
    return 301 https://$host:91$request_uri;

    ...
}

server {
    listen 91 ssl;
    server_name 100.100.100.100;

    ssl on;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/USER_FOLDER/APP_FOLDER/APP.sock;
    }

    ...
}
```

Не забываем открыть порт 91:

```
sudo ufw allow 91
```

Проверить конфиг nginx:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Если все ОК и никаких ошибок, то перечитываем конфиг Nginx:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```